# Lyx - put all text with same language

Tags: lyx, languages

So, I have this LyX file in a language "a", and I picked a text from other file with language "b".

How can I copy the text and be able to have the same language? Because now the copied text have a blue underline, meaning it is from a foreign language. This can be confirmed looking at the source code which has a

```
\foreignlanguage{english}{...}
```

Those underlines are very irritating... How can I remove them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The LyX support for multiple languages is indeed an annoyance if one does not want to switch languages within the same document. I have not yet found a way to specify on the document leven how to have the whole document in just one language, regardless whatever on copy&pastes into it.

As a workaround, I usually proceed as follows:

- *Edit->Select All*
- *Edit->Text Style->Customized...*
- In the text style dialog, you can change the language of the selected text.

Unfortunately, *Edit->Select All* does not really select all text. Float captions and footnotes are not automatically part of the selection. For these parts, some manual afterwork might be necessary.

Comment: Specifying that the document should just be in one language is a good feature request in my opinion. Please feel free to suggest it: http://www.lyx.org/trac. I suppose it would be implemented as a checkbox on Document Settings > Language

Answer (score 1):

If you have many floats and superscripts/subscripts, as I had in one of my documents, these will require quite a lot of manual work afterwards. You can use the Linux 'sed' command to edit the Lyx file directly, e.g.:

```
cat originalFile.lyx | sed -e '/\lang english/d' > fileWithoutLanguage.lyx
```

You can replace '\lang english' as appropriate.

Obviously there is a clear risk that you might end up screwing your file if you mess around with it outside the editor, but when I tested this on my code it seemed to work. I'd always suggest writing to a different file as I've done here.