# Multilingual documents with LyX?

Tags: lyx, languages

In some cases I need multiple languages in the same LyX document (e.g. when quoting an English text in a German document) and would like to have correct spell-checking for both parts.

LyX apparently supports multiple languages in a document to some degree, because copy-pasting text between documents of different languages results in some blue-underlined text with the different language being set. In LyX's internal format, this is represented by a structure like

```
This is English.
\lang ngerman 
 Hier wird es deutsch.
\lang english
 And german again.
```

and once such multi-lingual content has appeared in the document, language settings become available in the *Edit* menu.

[image: *Edit > Language*, available only after pasting mixed-language content.]

When removing the mixed language parts, the menu vanishes again, and thus I cannot find any method to add foreign-language content to a previously single-language document, without the inconvenient copy-paste workaround.

Is there some better way to mark some words as foreign-language?

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out in [Lyx - put all text with same language](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/56369/lyx-put-all-text-with-same-language), the answer can - somewhat unintuitively - be found in the *Edit → Text Style → Customized* dialog.

[image]

Comment: I agree it is not very intuitive. But I can't think of something better. If you have an idea for how to make it more intuitive, please open a ticket on https://www.lyx.org/trac